# How can I take random strings from a .txt file

Tags: python-2.7, random

I just started programming with python 2.7, and I have some trouble with my random generator for taking items from an outside .txt file, wondering if anyone could help me a little bit...

Basically Id like to take 100 random hits, and count them all up in the end, and print the summary for the strings. I hope it makes sense!

I know this question has been answered before, but the answeres havent helped me.

So, my txt file contains a bunch of strings, separated with commas.
This is what my code looks like:

```
import random

fname = raw_input("Enter filename: ")
infile = open(fname,'r')
data = infile.readlines()

for i in range(100):
   print(random.uniform("Car_types.txt"))
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just used a text file to test my code. The test file looks like this(not sure if your file is in the same format as mine).

```
import random
def addElements(l):
    for i in l:
        global result
        result.append(i)
fname=raw_input("Enter filename: ")
result=[]
summary=[]
for line in open(fname,'r'):
    elements=line.strip().split(',')
    addElements(elements)
for i in range(100):
    summary.append(random.choice(result))
print summary
```

1. test.txt:

abc,def,ghi

jkl,mno,pqr

2. Results:

['mno', 'ghi', 'pqr', 'jkl', 'abc', 'abc', 'jkl', 'jkl', 'jkl', 'def', 'pqr', 'def', 'jkl', 'pqr', 'mno', 'jkl', 'mno', 'def', 'jkl', 'jkl', 'def', 'mno', 'pqr', 'pqr', 'abc', 'pqr', 'def', 'abc', 'pqr', 'def', 'jkl', 'pqr', 'mno', 'mno', 'mno', 'def', 'jkl', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'pqr', 'mno', 'ghi', 'mno', 'mno', 'jkl', 'jkl', 'ghi', 'abc', 'ghi', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno', 'def', 'ghi', 'ghi', 'abc', 'abc', 'pqr', 'ghi', 'abc', 'abc', 'mno', 'def', 'jkl', 'mno', 'mno', 'jkl', 'jkl', 'pqr', 'pqr', 'pqr', 'jkl', 'def', 'jkl', 'mno', 'mno', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno', 'ghi', 'pqr', 'abc', 'ghi', 'def', 'ghi', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'def', 'abc', 'abc', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'pqr', 'pqr', 'pqr', 'def', 'pqr', 'pqr', 'def']

Hope this helps you out.

If it still prints out nonsense for you, please provide me how your txt file looks like. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you're looking for:

```
import random

fname = raw_input("Enter filename: ")
# With statements are better as they explicitly close the file
with open(fname,'r') as infile:
    data = infile.read().split(",")  # Split the strings with commas as you said

for i in range(100):
   print(random.choice(data))  # This will randomly choose one of the strings
```

Comment: Hi Bharel! Thanks for your advice, but I get nonsense as output.This is what I get:Enter filename: Car_types.txt
.
.
x
.
t
.
C
p
t
C
y
t
t
t
r
e
r
a
t
.
t
y
t
p

Comment: @Odani I'm not entirely sure how it's possible

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to potentially get the same values, take a *sample* after splitting the data on commas:

```
fname = raw_input("Enter filename: ")
with  open(fname) as f:
    for r in random.sample(f.read().split(), 100):
        print(r)
```

You are opening the file, calling readlines and then never using the content at all, `random.uniform("Car_types.txt"))` is acting on the literal string `"Car_types.txt"`, you need to use the actual file content.

Comment: Its working, but I still cant figure out how can I have a summarised output - every string counted up.